# Get voice from Mic

Tags: android

I am trying to start recording when there is voice is coming in mic end automatic stop when there is no voice.(i.e Talking Tom Application in android).

I can record voice and play them. I have also tried to in service start recording after every particular period of time but it's not good idea.

Can any one tell me the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Look at this project [NoiseAlert](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/wiki/NoiseAlert)
It shows one of the possibilities to analyze the mic volume.
App records the sound from the mic and every 300 milliseconds check `.getMaxAmplitude()`.